# Error python y tkinter con bucles

Tags: python, tkinter, bucles

Tengo un error al con python y tkinter al crear un programa que tiene un boton de salir y un atajo que es el f6 para salir al hacer el bucle para comprobar si estas pulsando F6 se me ejecuta el bucle antes que la ventana de tkinter se me queda con la consola esperando a que de F6 y cuando le doy se cierra yo quiero que se habra la ventana y despues se ejecute el bucle el codigo es este

```
from tkinter import ttk, Tk
import keyboard

root = Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")
def exitFunction():
    root.destroy()
ExitButton = ttk.Button(root, text="Salir F6", command=exitFunction).place(x=250, y=250)

while True:
    if keyboard.read_key("F6"):
        exitFunction()
    break

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que [keyboard.read_key()](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard#keyboardread_keysuppressfalse) es un código bloqueante, por lo que, aunque esté dentro del `while` se queda esperando a que se presione una tecla y no se ejecuta más nada del código (o sea, no se dibuja la ventana).

Luego, independiente de la tecla presionada, va a entrar al `if`, por lo que se llama a `exitFunction()` la cual destruye el objeto `root`. Todo eso ocurre antes de llegar a `root.mainloop()`.

Tkinter tiene [métodos propios](https://www.google.com/search?q=tkinter+bind+Key) para capturar teclas:

```py
from tkinter import ttk, Tk

root = Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")

def key_pressed(event):
    if event.keysym == "F6":
        exitFunction()

def exitFunction():
    root.destroy()

ExitButton = ttk.Button(root, text="Salir F6", command=exitFunction).place(x=250, y=250)
root.bind("<Key>", key_pressed)
root.mainloop()
```

Otra forma un poco más corta:

```py
from tkinter import ttk, Tk

root = Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")

def exitFunction():
    root.destroy()

ExitButton = ttk.Button(root, text="Salir F6", command=exitFunction).place(x=250, y=250)
root.bind("<F6>", lambda event:exitFunction())
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Muchas gracias habia mirado en muchos sitios y no encontraba solucion

Comment: No existe alguna manera de que siga capturando teclas aun teniendo la ventana minimizada