# atajos python y tkinter en pestaña minimizada

Tags: python, tkinter, atajo

Estoy creando un programa que tiene un atajo al tocar F6 se cierra pero cuando tengo la pestaña minimizada el deja de leerme las teclas el programa usa tkinter

```
exitButton = ttk.Button(text="Exit F6", command=exitFunction).place(x=92, y=150)
root.bind("<F6>", lambda event:exitFunction())
```

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: El problema parece viene de [este otro](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/548729/80870). Y no creo que sea posible. Al minimizar la ventana se cambia el espacio de trabajo a la ventana que esté en primer plano, o en su defecto al entorno global de sistema operativo. Cada uno de esos espacios de trabajo tienen su propio comportamiento. No puedes cerrar, ni el Word, ni el Chrome con un hotkey cuando estan minimizados ¿Por que una aplicación tkinter si podría hacerlo?

Comment: En realidad si es posible usando modulos que capturen eventos globales de teclado. Pero mi pregunta es... Que debería suceder si el usuario apreta f6 con una intención **distinta** a "quiero usar este atajo para cerrar este programa"... Yo no lo haría y dejaría que funcione solo cuando la ventana tiene el foco.